# Google speech to text live stream, single_utterance is not working

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api

I'm trying live stream speech to text using Google. I have installed node into my server.

I have successfully implemented it but I want google to recognize when the user stops to speaking. Google explained how to do that using single_utterance=true but it is not taking effect. Can you please tell what issue is there in the below code. Thank you!

```
var request = {
config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
    //profanityFilter: false,
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    //single_utterance: true
    // speechContexts: [{
    //     phrases: ["hoful","shwazil"]
    //    }] // add your own speech context for better recognition
},
interimResults: true, // If you want interim results, set this to true
singleUtterance: true
};


function startRecognitionStream(client, data) {
    console.log(request);
    recognizeStream = speechClient.streamingRecognize(request)
        .on('error', console.error)
        .on('data', (data) => {
            process.stdout.write(
                (data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0])
                    ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
                    : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`);
            client.emit('speechData', data);

            // if end of utterance, let's restart stream
            // this is a small hack. After 65 seconds of silence, the stream will still throw an error for speech length limit
            if (data.results[0] && data.results[0].isFinal) {
                stopRecognitionStream();
                startRecognitionStream(client);
                // console.log('restarted stream serverside');
            }
        })
        .on('end_of_single_utterance', (data) => {
            process.stdout.write('data ended');
            console.log('data ended');
        })
        ;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The bottom of your `config` object shows `singleUtterance: true`. Did you forget the underscore?

Comment: @LenJoseph I have tried that as well but didn't get a response in end_of_single_utterance event in any case.